# Google Play: age group and family program

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I recently submitted an app on Google Play and it was rejected. The app has age group 4+ (in this case the app must fulfill requirements of family program). The app contains ads (banner at the bottom and full screen ads) from Google (AdMob).
My app is not specifically for children but for absolutely everyone. What shall I do now? I don't want my app to target 13+. Is there a way to stick to age group 4+ and keeping the ads? Or age group 13+ is the only way out?
Google says that in case of 4+ some special SDK for ads must be used.

Thanks
Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to me, just go for 13+. If you go for 4+, Google will be keeping an eye on your app every single second. A few reports can get you off Play Store. The same happened with me- I had 5 apps in minor category. One day, they decided to just delete my developer account.

Comment: I really don't understand what Google wants from me. I've seen tons of apps for all ages with all kinds of ads. They say: For ad requests that are served to children audiences, in order to receive Google Play’s Families policy-compliant ads from third-party ad networks, you will need to call tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true) and set max_ad_content_rating to G for every ad request. What does it mean?